# How websites check for user login status?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What type of security maintained in any website or web application. After login, Whenever we copy the address from address bar and paste it to the other browser , the page cannot be open or we get redirected directly to login page. But same address can be opened in same browser. So I want to ask that,how the security is maintained and what it called??Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) the whole security model is based on cookies. So when a user logs in an authentication cookie is emitted for the session of the browser. This cookie is then sent along on each request. The cookie could be persistent (i.e. stored on the local disk) and will survive browser restarts or it could be not-persistent in which case it only lives in the memory of the browser.

This cookie contains an encrypted value of the currently logged in username, which allows the server to decrypt this cookie and *recognize* this user.

When you move on another browser, there is no cookie being sent, so from the server's perspective the user is not authenticated and it gets redirected to the login page if he tries to access some protected resource.

Answer (score 3):

## Cookie

Browsers work with cookie and authentication is mainly (almost always) done via cookie. The procedure is this way:

1. You go to a website by entering the URL of the site into the address bar.
2. Browser checks to see if there is any cookie (key/value pair) set for that URL
3. If there is any set cookie, browser sends those cookies alongside HTTP Request.
4. That website checks for that cookie, before letting you see the requested content (before sending you back the response)
5. If you have the cookie, it responds.
6. If not, it redirects you to another page (login page) where it can ask your user name and password (most simple authentication mechanism).
7. When you provide your user name and password, it simply sends you a cookie (authentication cookie).