# LoginStatus does not recognise when a user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, forms-authentication

I've got an `asp:LoginStatus` control, which is supposed to change to 'Log out' when a user logs in.

However, I have not managed to create the login process. I've coded the login process myself using a Session (i.e. a database is checked to validate user-provided username and password, and if valid, my code sets a Session to true, and redirects to the page which he/she may now access).

There should be no problem with the above part, as it works well. The problem is with this LoginStatus control. I have read that the control checks for `isAuthenticated`, but I don't know how to set this property. Can the LoginStatus only be used with cookies, and is it not working due to my Session method of authentication?

I've set the login page and authentication type to "Forms" in the Web.config.

Any suggestions?

Comment: take alook at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454883/how-websites-check-for-user-login-status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mimic what the login control does; it uses `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to establish the user security cookie, then redirects from the login page.  That's what you have to use for testing.  You have to do a  redirect because during the lifecycle when you set the cookie, the framework doesn't think your logged in, until after the redirect.

Comment: So do I have to do away with me Session method? Or do I use cookies aswell as the session?

Comment: @Sean you can still use Session, but if you want to use the .NET framework login and other security controls, you have to use the formsauthentication object and create the cookie.  The cookie also fuels the Page.User.Identity object, which is the forms principal that contains the name of the user, and whether they are authenticated.  Note: session and cookie expiration can happen at different times, so to manage the 2, you have to be careful there.